# ComponentWillMount called after redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

So when I'm on a Book Page, and click a button to delete it, it should redirect to my User Profile and delete the Book from the database. But what happens is ComponentWillMount is called again for the Book and it can't find it. Maybe I don't have a clear understanding of these lifecycle methods but I thought ComponentWillMount will only be called once when first rendering? Also using Firebase for the database.

Here's the relevant code (where Book == WIP):

WIP.js

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.WIPRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let WIP = snapshot.val()
      this.setState({
        title: WIP.title ? WIP.title : "",
        wordCount: WIP.wc ? WIP.wc : "",
        logline: WIP.logline ? WIP.logline : "",
        draft: WIP.draft ? WIP.draft : "",
        language: WIP.language ? WIP.language : "",
        disclaimers: WIP.disclaimers ? WIP.disclaimers : "",
        improvementAreas: WIP.improvementAreas ? WIP.improvementAreas : "",
        blurb: WIP.blurb ? WIP.blurb : "",
        additionalNotes: WIP.additionalNotes ? WIP.additionalNotes : "",
        writer: WIP.writer ? WIP.writer : "",
        genres: WIP.genres ? WIP.genres : [],
        types: WIP.types ? WIP.types : []
      });
      var promises = []
      var writerRef = firebaseDB.database().ref(`/Users/${WIP.writer}`)
      promises.push(writerRef.once('value')); 
      Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
        snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
          var writer = snapshot.val()
          this.setState({
            writerName: writer.displayName ? writer.displayName : ""
          })
        })
      })
    })
}


removeWIP(WIPId) {
    this.setState({ redirect: true })
    const usersWIPRef = firebaseDB.database().ref(`/Users/${this.state.writer}/WIPs/${this.state.wipId}`)
    this.deleteWIPIndexRecord(this.state.wipId)
    usersWIPRef.remove();
    this.WIPRef.remove();
  }

deleteWIPIndexRecord(wipId) {
    const WIPRef = firebaseDB.database().ref(`WIPs/${wipId}`);
    WIPRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    // Get Algolia's objectID from the Firebase object key
    const objectID = snapshot.key;
    // Remove the object from Algolia
    wipsIndex
      .deleteObject(objectID)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Firebase object deleted from Algolia', objectID);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error when deleting contact from Algolia', error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
    })
  }






render() {
    if (this.state.redirect === true) {
      return <Redirect to= {{pathname: '/user/' + this.state.writer}} />
    }
    return(
        <Button className="black-bordered-button" 
                      onClick={() => this.removeWIP(WIP.id)}
              >
            Remove Item
        </Button>
    )
  }
```

But then when I delete the book I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null` from this line in `ComponentWillMount` `title: WIP.title ? WIP.title : ""`

Comment: can you show mode code where `delete action` is called

Comment: can you provide all the component code? I am specially interested in the configuration. I am wondering if some state element related to this deleted item is refreshed somewhere triggering the rendering on this component or components above.

Comment: Edited to add more relevant code. Here is a link to all the component code: https://github.com/mayaah/critique-connect/blob/master/src/components/WIP.js

Comment: I think it's not componentWillMount, but your `on.value` listener.. maybe you should detach your listener in your component willunmount? this is a nice reference from firebase itself: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-detaching-callbacks

Comment: A primitive yet simplest way to check is to use `alert` in `componentWillMount()` before your listener. Does the alert run once or multiple times?

Comment: Yeah I thought I did do `this.WIPRef.off();` in my `componentWillUnmount` :/  The alert does not run at all when I delete the book/WIP which is weird b/c it does end up in `componentWillMount` when I debug in console. And when I add `this.WIPRef.off();` to my `removeWIP` function it still errors the same

Comment: Ok, I might have put a bandaid on it by having a null check on `WIP` in `componentWillMount` and if it's not null, then set the state. But idk if this is the best solution.

Comment: I would prefer to use inside `constructor` instead of `componentWillMount `.